# I want to display the total amount of the listbox items in label

Tags: label

As below I want the total to be displayed in the label1. How can I do that?

[image]

```
namespace TEST
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-93HPJ15\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds;
        private int i;
        private IFormatProvider async;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-93HPJ15\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
            cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Producten", con);
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + " | " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + " | € " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);

            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string revomeItemFromList = listBox1.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Remove(revomeItemFromList);
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider tagging the technology you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the `Form1_Load` method. Inside the loop that iterates over the dataset rows, add up the values into a variable. Then, display the value of that variable:

```cs
// Variable to store total value
decimal totalValue = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
{

    comboBox1.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0] + " | " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1] + " | € " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2]);

    // Sum up total value
    totalValue += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2];
}

// Update label to show total value
label1.Text = totalValue.ToString("#.00");
```

Comment: Dear Serge. Thank you for responding. Regarding your code Iam getting the following error "cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'decimal'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast).". Do you have any idea what Iam doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of `totalValue += ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2];`, try `totalValue += (decimal)ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2];`.

Comment: The same now Iam getting the following exception.InvalidCastException was unhandled